# React useEffect but after set state value and only once

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to migrate some of my old componentDidMount code to the new useEffect hooks and I'm having problems figuring out how to emulate the callback behavior of setState

I have an array of stuff that gets pulled from an api, I need to call a function only after the state and been loaded and then only once

Previous code:

```
ComponentDidMount() {
  const response = await getMyArrayFromAPI
  this.setState({ myArray }, () => { initializeArray() })
}
```

Current code:

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([])

useEffect(() = {
  const response = await getMyArrayFromAPI
  setMyArray(response)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // one time initialization of data

  // initially gets called before myArray has value, when it should be after
  // gets called every time myArray changes, instead of only once

}, [myArray])
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Why not put the one time initialization of data inside the first `useEffect` hook? Make the API call, set the array, initialize the data, all one time due to the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `myArray` in the first `useEffect` function, but if you want to use separate functions you can just check if it's empty

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!myArray.length) {
    // one time initialization
  }
}, [myArray])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state to drive whether or not `initializeArray` needs to run e.g.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  getMyArrayFromAPI.then(data => setArray(data || []));
}, []);
if (array) {
  // this will only ever run once as we don't set `array` 
  // anywhere other than `useEffect`
  initializeArray();
}
```

Depending on what `initializeArray` actually does, you could run it from inside `then` but that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a custom setState hook to manage your callback

```
const useMyCustomStateHook = (initState, cb) => {
 const [customState, updateCustomState] = useState(initState);

 useEffect(() => cb(customState), [customState, cb]);

 return [customState, updateCustomState];
};
```

So you could then have

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} = from 'react'
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useMyCustomStateHook([], initializeArray)

useEffect(() = {
  const response = await getMyArrayFromAPI
  setMyArray(response)
}, [])
```